# Swapping strings. I want to do this using getChars() and String Concat() function. Don't know how to in java

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do: Given a string from user, swap the first half with second half. If the string length is odd, take the lower first half and swap. And if the string length is 1, leave it alone. For Example:

Input: abcde

Output: cdeab

```
class swap20
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String str = str.nextInt();
        int length = str.length();
        System.out.println("The length is:-"+length);
        int L1 = length/2
        int L2 = length-L1;
        void getChars( int 0, int L1, char[] dst1, 0 );
        //String second = void getChars( int (L1+1), int length, char[] dst2, 0);
        //str1 = str1.concat(String second );
        System.out.println(str1);
}

}
```

Comment: You should read a basic tutorial because your syntax is pretty broken. Search how to create methods in Java.

Comment: what is `String Str = s.nextInt();` Is it compilable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pal!I have an answer.

```
package THE_JNOTE_PROJECT;
import java.util.*;

class Swap {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    int l=(s.length())/2;
    char ar[]=new char[l];
    char data[]=new char[s.length()-l];
    s.getChars(0,l,ar,0);
    s.getChars(l,s.length(),data,0);
    String first=new String(ar);
    String sec=new String(data);
    System.out.println(sec.concat(first));
}
}
```

Try this out!

Comment: @High-Cyber,you truly need to improve your syntax and logic to a great extent.Sorry to say.

Comment: Thanks! and Yes I'm trying to learn and I guess i'll be there in sometime soon if i keep working on more programs (Y) :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead by using the substring() method. Given a string str:

```
String str = "quicksand";
String firstHalf = str.substring(0, str.length() / 2);
String secondHalf = str.substring(str.length() / 2);

String finalString = "";

if (str.length() == 1)
{
    finalString = str;
}
else
{
    finalString = secondHalf.concat(firstHalf);
}
```

Comment: This is not OP's exact problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, Ah, you're right - I misunderstood what he meant by "lower half." I'll update it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Actually, to be honest, I'm still not entirely sure I understand what he means about the string length being odd or even.

Answer (score 0):

In java, you cannot directly define a method inside another method. You need to define and implement the method outside:

```
class Swap20 {
    public static String swapByHalf(String stringToSwap) {
        //implementation of the method...
        int length = stringToSwap.length();
        return stringToSwap.substring(length / 2) + stringToSwap.substring(0, length / 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String str = s.next();
        int length = str.length();
        System.out.println("The length is: " + length);
        //String second = swapByHalf(str);
        //str = str.concat(second);
        System.out.println(swapByHalf(str));
    }
}
```

Still, there are some problems with your code. For example, `a` is an undeclared variable, and you should call `s.close()` at the end of the method. Also, Java **is not** C nor C++, so you don't need to work with `char[]`, instead you have `String` class for it. I suggest you to review the basics by reading [The Java Tutorials. Trail: Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/)

Comment: Thankyou so much! Yes i'm trying to improve and the link Sir (Y) :D